# Self outer Join alternative for inserting into Physical table from Temp table

Tags: sql-server, database-performance

How to improve the performance of this query?

```
INSERT INTO ABC(TRACKING_ID,GROUP_ID,ETL_NUM,ENTITY_ID,UNI_ID,DOS_TO)
SELECT A.TID,A.TID2,A.ETL_NUM,A.ENTITY_ID,A.UNI_ID,A.DOS_TO
FROM #TEMP A(NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN #TEMP B(NOLOCK) ON A.TID=B.TID
AND ETL_NUM<B.ETL_NUM
WHERE B.TID IS NULL
```

I have 11 million records. It takes 9 hours to process this query. For tuning this query i have added index on Temp table ETL_NUM. But it didnt improve performance.

I don't have Admin privileges on DB.

Comment: Add a single index on the table for ID and ETL_NUM

Answer (score 0):

Could you make it clearer?

Do you want to insert 11millions records into the DB you don't have Admin authority?

And you want to insert all the data manually? So, you think it takes around 9 hours. Or for just one query you wrote down takes 9hours?

Well, If you are talking about the former one, It depends how you have the data. If you have the data in JSON or in a stylesheet or this kind of file. It can be easier. If it is latter one, you may need to ask the admin and discuss about it.

Comment: It is inside stored procedure.1) First step it creates #TEMP table 2) TEMP table gets populated in 5 min 3) last step i try inserting in ABC table it with self outer join condition it takes 9 hours to run the query. The reason i mentioned i dont have admin priviliges is, i cant create trace or use profiler.