# Rewrite the query to tune performance

Tags: sql-server, performance

```
INSERT INTO ABC(TRACKING_ID,GROUP_ID,ETL_NUM,ENTITY_ID,UNI_ID,DOS_TO)
SELECT A.TID,A.TID2,A.ETL_NUM,A.ENTITY_ID,A.UNI_ID,A.DOS_TO
FROM #TEMP A(NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN #TEMP B(NOLOCK) ON A.TID=B.TID
AND ETL_NUM<B.ETL_NUM
WHERE B.TID IS NULL
```

Suggest an alternative way to write above query to improve performance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Self outer Join alternative for inserting into Physical table from Temp table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49714734/self-outer-join-alternative-for-inserting-into-physical-table-from-temp-table)

Comment: It does no good to post duplicate questions - especially when you also don't provide the same level of information.

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure there are indexes on TID and ETL_NUM, however the OUTER JOIN is going to be a performance problem, as is the < operator.

You might get a performance boost by eliminating the temp table if it possible to optimize whatever you're loading it from.

Comment: I have added index still the performance improvement is hardy one 1.5 hours. I have 110,926,810 records. Can we rewrite this whole query? Or is it ok if i copy data in TEMP A, TEMP B and do left outer join of A & B. instead Self join?

Comment: I have rewritten the query. Added data to 2 temp tables and did the leftouter join. Now code takes only 20 Min to insert the data.